# Kio estas la diferenco inter 'nura' kaj 'sola'?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Nu, mi ne scias ĉu ekzistas eta diferenco inter la du, aŭ ĉu ili estas tute similaj adjektivoj?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La vorto *nura* esprimas nesufiĉecon; la vorto *sola* esprimas foreston de kunuloj.

> *Li ne estas viro. Eĉ kun nia helpo, la tasko estos malfacila por **nura** knabo.*
>
> *Li staras ekster la lernejo sen aliaj infanoj. Li estas **sola** knabo.*

Rimarku la diferencon inter *sola* kaj *sole*:

> *Mi spektas sola.* (Mi spektas sen kunspektantoj.)
>
> *Mi spektas sole.* (Mi spektas sed faras nenion alian.)
>
> *Mi nur spektas.* (Mi spektas kiam iu eble atendas aldonajn agojn de mi.)